# How can I get the label of the option in the parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, ref

I am using React Hook forms in my project and the problem is that I cannot get the label from timeGrainOptionsList.

```
<SelectFormField
            data-testid="timeGrain"
            fieldType="Select"
            fieldSize="medium"
            tableSelect={true}
            name="timeGrain"
            label="Time Grain"
            placeHolder="Select time grain"
            control={control}
            options={timeGrainOptionsList}
            defaultValue={R.pathOr('P1D', ['time', 'timeGrain', 'defaultValue'], configurationTemplate)}
            required={R.pathOr(false, ['time', 'timeGrain', 'required'], configurationTemplate)}
          />
```

And here is the format of timeGrainOptionsList:

```
[{label: "abc", value: "dfdf"}, {label: "abc", value: "dfdf"}]
```

The problem is, 'options' only forwards the value of the input field to the parent component.

```
const { timeColumn, widgetMetrics, timeGrain } = watch();
```

I want it so that I can also get the timeGrainLabel like so:

```
const { timeColumn, widgetMetrics, timeGrain, timeGrainLabel } = watch();
```

Basically I want to pass it on to another component from here:

```
<PreviewWidgetContent
            isValidConfigs={isValid}
            assetID={assetID}
            timeColumn={timeColumn}
            timeGrain={timeGrain}
            dataWidgetID={dataWidgetID}
            formValues={formValues}
            columnsList={columnsList}
            dataWidgetMeta={dataWidgetMeta}
          />
```

I have tried this:

```
options={timeGrainOptionsList.map(option => ({ ...option, timeGrainLabel: option.label }))}
```

But it doesn't work. What can I do here?